# g_slist_copy_deep returns segmentation fault

Tags: c, gtk3, glib

Looking for assistance on copying a `GSList` using `g_slist_copy_deep`.

I have a `GSList` of bank accounts structs (account number and description), and I want to use `g_slist_copy_deep` to copy that `GSList` to another `GSList`. I get a seg fault in my copy function.

First the structure definition.

```c
typedef struct Accounts {
    gchar number[100];
    gchar description[500];
} Account;
```

Next, the copy function.

```c
GCopyFunc build_temporary_list(gpointer master_account, gpointer user_data) {

    /* Retrieve current master account */
    GSList *master_account_ptr = (GSList *)master_account_list;
    Account * account_ptr = (Account *)master_account_ptr->data;
    Account master_account = *account_ptr; /*Seg fault here */

    /* Copy master account into a new temporary account */
    Account temporary_account;
    strcpy(temporary_account.number,master_account.number);
    strcpy(temporary_account.description,master_account.description);

}
```

Creating the master list and then the temporary copy.

```c
GSList *master_account_list = read_account_numbers(); /* This statment works correctly, producing a GSList with four accounts. */

GSList *temporary_account_list = g_slist_copy_deep(master_account_list, (GCopyFunc) build_temporary_list, NULL);
```

As noted above, I get a seg fault when attempting to retrieve the current master account.
Follow up question: After I successfully initialize a new temporary account, how is it added to the list of copied temporary accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`g_slist_copy_deep()` calls the provided copy function on each list item, more specifically on the item's data. The copy function you have here gets both the function signature wrong, *and* doesn't return anything.

A possible example for your use case could be the following:

```
gpointer build_temporary_list(gpointer item, gpointer user_data) {
    Account *master_account = item;

    /* Copy master account into a new temporary account */
    Account* temp_account = g_new (Account, 1);
    strcpy(temp_account->number, master_account->number);
    strcpy(temp_account->description, master_account->description);

    return temp_account;
}
```

Comment: Your explanation and code sample were my salvation. My project compiles and runs as expected. Thank you.